# Объясните пожалуйста почему значение а выводит 60

Tags: php

Объясните  пожалуйста почему значение а выводит 60 в PHP

```
<?php
  
  $a = 0;
    $b = 0;
    for( $i=0; $i<=5; $i++ )
    {
        $a += 10;
        $b += 5;
    }
    echo "<br />Sfarsitul ciclu,si valoare lui a=".$a.",iar a lui b=".$b;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

0,1,2,3,4,5 ноль тоже считается

Comment: все я поняла, я не заметила =5,я смотрела как меньше 5 а там равно еще